# Need to wait until the object size reaches the expected in Capybara

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, capybara, site-prism

Currently i can use this below code to verify the object size:

```
expect((@page.elements).size).to eq(12)
```

But i want to use `wait_for` / `wait_until` command until those `elements(collection of objects)` loads. So i want to use like this below:

```
@page.wait_until_elements.size == 12
```

How can i do that? Please help.

Comment: what kind of object is it?

Comment: its pageobject which has common className for multiple objects. i have defined that in the page like this:  elements :items, "#id .className". So items hold multiple objects and i want to wait until all object loads. Here's items size is 12

Answer (score 0):

A number of the Site-Prism methods support the Capybara query options. In this particular case, you can use the `:count` option to specify the exact number you want to wait for.

```
expect(@page).to have_elements :count => 12, :wait => 10
```

For more details, see the [Using Capybara Query Options](https://github.com/natritmeyer/site_prism#using-capybara-query-options) section of the documentation.

Comment: expected #has_elements?({:count=>12}) to return true, got false (RSpec::Expectations::ExpectationNotMetError)     Doesn't work . It never waits for those objects.

Comment: I forgot that Capybara does not wait by default. Therefore you will want to specify the `:wait` parameter.

Comment: I tried waiting for lengths of that objects to load using loop. And it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Worth pointing out that whilst the answers here are from a while ago (And for anyone else finding this answer since), the quality of capybara queries has vastly increased.

The best option here to use is probably `minimum: 12` which would wait until you have at least 12 of them, and it would wait the `Capybara.default_wait_time` implicitly

If you wanted to use a waiter in-line you could also specify that with a wait key

`@page.elements(wait: 3, minimum: 12)` - This would wait up to 3 seconds before complaining the set of elements wasn't there or until you had 12. In which case it would continue.